# Applying const_cast on this-> pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this, const-cast

I was playing with some code to remove constant-ness of variable.

```
  int *i = new int(202);
  int *j = new int(402);

  int *const iptr = i;    // Constant pointer
  //iptr = j ;           // Not allowed. Constant pointer cannot point to another location.
  (*iptr)++;             // Allowed
  const_cast<int *>(iptr) = j;
  cout<< *iptr           // prints 402
```

It works as expected but when I try to remove constantness of "this" pointer, Compiler doesnt allow it, i.e. it shows squiggling lines underneath the const_cast statement.

```
class A
{
public:
  A(A * obj)
  {
    const_cast<A *>(this) = obj; 
  }
};
```

When I hovered mouse (I am using VS2014) over "this" and "iptr" from earlier code, I could see the type is same i.e. `<classname> *const`

Can anybody please explain what is going on under the hood?

Cheers,

Saket

Comment: `iptr` is a `const` object. Modifying it is undefined behavior under any circumstance. So, `const_cast<int *>(iptr) = j;` is semantically wrong (and that's not a surprise -- you are lying to the compiler.)

Comment: Don't cast away constness willy-nilly, because that is a great way to get [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you don't want something to be constant, then you should not make it constant.

Comment: We should add a feature that auto-replies `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` questions by users under 5k rep (yes, that includes me) with: **Don't touch this, you gonna hurt yourself!**

Comment: As for your problem, you don't know the thoughts or the intentions of the user of class `A`, casting away the constness might even be highly destructive and lead to crashes down the line. Also, if you want to allow copying then add a proper copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator.

Comment: What would it mean to assign to `this`?

Comment: You're assigning to `this`? Interesting, and completely illegal. `this` is defined by the standard as a prvalue expression (prvalue = *pure rvalue*). it can't appear on the lhs of an assignment. `this = ....` isn't legal, and casting isn't going to change that. See C++11 § 9.3.2,p1. [class.this].

Comment: You can however do `*this = *obj`.

Comment: You can't assign to `this` under any circumstances, it behaves as a literal.

Comment: `cout<< *iptr; // prints 402` is not working as expected, as there is no expectation, as it is undefined behaviour. A compiler which did some optimizating would be within its rights to output 203

Comment: @WhozCraig: That is worth an answer.

Comment: Actually it doesn't even compile. It "should" be  `const_cast<int *&>(iptr) = j;`

Comment: It is not the const cast that is the big problem. As written above it is assignment to the this ptr. The title to the question is therefore misleading. const cast can be made, but not assignment to this ptr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is not an l-value.

You cannot assign it to point to something else.

You can do `*this = *obj;` which does not require a `const_cast`

You can do a `const_cast<A*>(this)` to override constness, and as with any other const_cast is fraught with danger, but it would enable you to perform a const/non-const overload without having to duplicate the implementation e.g.

```
T& A::get()
{
 // some complex code to find the right reference, assigning to t
  return t;
}

const T& A::get() const
{
// implement in terms of above function
  return (const_cast<A*>(this))->get(); // invokes above
 // and automatically converts the reference to const
}
```

Comment: I think the example is wrong. The const/non-const overload trick can only safely be used the other way round. The non-const version needs to call the const version and then suitably cast the return value of the const version. Because the non-const version knows it is invoked on a non-const object, and it can also invoke the const version. The const version may theoretically be invoked on an object in read only storage, and calling the non const version will then likely crash.

Comment: If you have implemented the non-const version and know it doesn't modify anything, just that it returns a non-const reference, then my code is safe. But yes you can do it the other way round, either way you end up with a const_cast.

Comment: If you have implemented a non-const version and it doesn't modify anything, then it isn't the *non*-const version and you should declare it const so that the compiler can check your assumption :-)

Comment: It doesn't modify anything but returns a reference to a member variable that requires the function to be non-const.

Yes, you could implement it the other way round, I probably would, but I wanted to give an example where const_cast on this might be reasonable. The "implement the other way round" is one of the cases where const_cast is reasonable at all, usually one should avoid.

Comment: Btw, there is exactly this construct in [LLVM codebase](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/DeclCXX_8h_source.html):   1) "CXXRecordDecl *getCanonicalDecl() override {
     return cast<CXXRecordDecl>(RecordDecl::getCanonicalDecl());
   }" And 2) " const CXXRecordDecl *getCanonicalDecl() const {
     return const_cast<CXXRecordDecl*>(this)->getCanonicalDecl();
  }"

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid you did not understand what `const_cast` is for.

In C++, `const` is used in two instances:

- a `const` object logical value cannot be changed (and, barring `mutable` fields, its bitwise value cannot be changed either)
- `const*` or `const&` are read-only pointers or references

`const_cast` is not about changing `const` objects, it's about modifying non-const objects through read-only pointers or references

Bear in mind though that shooting yourself in the foot is easy, because when you get a `const&` how do you know whether the original object is `const` or not ? You do not. And if you attempt to change one that *is* `const`, *a unicorn appears, or maybe the devil* (also know as Undefined Behavior: anything may happen).

Now, the correlation with `this` is tricky. Strictly speaking `this` is an r-value (meaning it can only appear as-is on the **R** ight-hand side of `=`), though it is often described as simply being `const` for simplicity's sake, so in a constructor of `A` `this` is described as having type `A* const`. Thankfully for us, even in this approximation `const_cast` is a bad idea since the original object is `const`.

---

Therefore, the recommendation is:

- **Junior**: Do not use `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or C-style casts (because it is not obvious when they desugar to one of the first two).
- **Senior**: You are not experienced enough.
- **Expert**: Come on! How can you claim you are an expert and attempt to use them ?

Comment: also, `this` is an rvalue and not an lvalue, as such it can only be used as argument of a function, not to store results or to  get a reference/pointer

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering why compiler allowed in first place and not when I tried with this pointer.

Comment: @pqnet: good point, I forgot about addressing `this` mid-way; corrected.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeh but it is the opposite, that is `this` is not an `l-value` but an `r-value`. `this` can't appear on the left side of an `=`

Comment: @pqnet: Exact, got my left and right mixed up here :x